# Resolve doesn't wait for API call to complete before falling to end of function

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am making an Angular 4 web app. I have a page that needs to wait for data before displaying so I'm using resolve. First resolve checks if the data is available in storage, if it is check if the ids in the route and data match, if not, retrieve the data from the API, and finally if the data does not exist in storage retrieve it from the API. However the function always falls to the end if API calls are made. What am I doing wrong?

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<PDataInterface>
{
  const routeID = route.params.id;
  // get data from storage
  this.getData();
  if (!!this.pData) {
    if (this.pData.id == routeID) {
      return Observable.of(this.pData);
    } else {
      this.API.getInfo(this.routeID).subscribe((data) => {
        this.pData = data;
        return Observable.of(this.pData);
      });
    }
  } else {
    this.API.getInfo(this.pData.id).subscribe((data) => {
      this.pData = data;
      return Observable.of(this.pData);
    });
  }
  // function always comes here if API calls are made
  console.log("failed resolve");
  this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
}
```

api.ts

```
getInfo(id) {
    const URL = `${this.API}/paintline/${id}`;
    return this.refreshToken()
      .flatMap(() => this.authHttp.get(URL, this.headers))
      .map((response: Response) => response.json().data)
      .share()
      .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

This is the `refreshToken()` that is called in `getInfo()`. It refreshes my JWT token if its expired before making the request to the backendd

```
refreshToken(): Observable<any>
{
  const URL = `${this.API}/refresh?token=${this.token}`;
  if (this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(this.token)) {
    return this.authHttp.get(URL)
      .map((rsp) =>
        {
          this.setToken(rsp.json().token);
          this.authNotifier.next(true);
          return rsp.json().token;
        },
        err =>
        {
          this.authNotifier.next(false);
          this.logout();
          console.log(err);
        })
      .share();
  }
  else { return Observable.of(this.token); }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
{
        {
          path: 'details',
          component: PDetailsComponent,
          resolve: {pData: PResolverService}
        },
}]
```

Comment: probably read about asynchounous javascript, it's supposed to get to the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you subscribe to your api, your API is fired but the rest of the resolve code continues to execute. That is why it keeps reaching your `console.log("failed resolve");`. Instead you should return the api observable and let the resolver do the subscribe.

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<PDataInterface>
{
    const routeID = route.params.id;
    // get data from storage
    this.getData();
    if (!!this.pData) {
        if (this.pData.id == routeID) {
            return Observable.of(this.pData);
        } else {
            return this.API.getInfo(this.routeID);
        }
    } else {
        return this.API.getInfo(this.pData.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I added my API call to the OP along with `refreshToken()` which refreshes my jwt token if its expired before making any calls to the API. Do I have to modify it to return the observable? Because I have to subscribe to it

Comment: @derrickrozay It looks like the `refreshToken()` method does return an observable. Then you are chaining your refreshToken observable and authHttp.get observable. So altogether the resolve is receiving an observable sequence, which is correct.

Comment: Currently I return `pData` which is an array and I can access that in my component. If I do it the way you recommend how would I access the data? I am just using map in `getInfo()` I still need to subscribe to it otherwise it'll never make the request

Comment: @derrickrozay The resolve will actual do the subscribe when you navigate to the route. Looking at the code, where does the resolve get pData?

Comment: I've added the router module to the OP, its expecting a `pData` array

Comment: @derrickrozay with your setup, the router knows to subscribe to the resolve method of your PResolverService. So whatever observable you return in that resolve method will be subscribed to and the result will return to pData

Comment: Wow it works! Cool thing is that pData initially comes from session storage, and in my component when I retrieve pData and assign it to another pData variable it automatically updates my session storage! I didnt know that was possible or how its done but it saves me the work of doing it !

Comment: Weird. It seems its smart enough to work when I click on the buttons and goto the route, but I change the id in the URL manually it says that `pData` is returning true.  Same thing also happens if `pData` isn't in storage and it goes to the last else in your code. Any idea why this is? I'm guessing because the router module isnt called so it doesn't know how to resolve it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157682/discussion-between-llai-and-derrickrozay).